# Pause Video Recording Using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera, avfoundation

I created a custom camera that works perfectly so far. I can record a video and stop recording with no errors or bugs. A feature i would like to add to this camera is the ability to pause a recording.

After a lot of research online, i see the solution is to actually stop the recording when the pause button is clicked, and to begin another recording when the resume button is clicked. After that you are supposed to merge the videos together.

I am not sure how to merge videos, i looked a lot of things up online and have not been able to find a solution.

Thank you!

**This is my recording button function**

```
@IBAction func recordVideoButtonPressed(sender:AnyObject) {

    if self.movieFileOutput.isRecording {
        isRecording = false
        self.movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
    } else {
        isRecording = true
        self.movieFileOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = self.videoOrientation()
        self.movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = self.maxRecordedDuration()
        self.movieFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: self.videoFileLocation()), recordingDelegate: self)
    }

    self.updateRecordButtonTitle()

}
```

**This is my pause button function**

```
 func pauseVideo() {
    if isRecording {
        if isPaused == false {
            isPaused = true
            recordButton.isEnabled = false
            recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.wetAsphalt
            recordButton.setTitle("Paused", for: .normal)
        } else {
            isPaused = false
            recordButton.isEnabled = true
            recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            updateRecordButtonTitle()
        }
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide: func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) method code?

Answer (score 1):

You can write all frames with `AVAssetWriter`. You need to use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to get frames from camera. [Here](https://github.com/remirobert/CameraEngine/tree/master/CameraEngine) You can find an exmaple.

Or if you want to merge  videos checkout [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift) tutorial.